# Google people api, how access to field FileAS

Tags: google-people-api

In the Google Contacts under show more there is the field File As. How can I get it?

I have a Contact with only company name. So people names will not be supplied. But I set File As differently than company. But I don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the "File As" property is not supported by the People API. The only supported fields are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#query-parameters).

Feel free to file a feature request here: https://developers.google.com/people/support#missing_features

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2020 this was implemented by Google. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155947710
However the API docs were not updated. You need to request the "fileAses" property. Example in PHP:

```
// Retrieve the first 20 results from the database
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 20,
    'personFields' => 'names,fileAses',
);
$results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);
foreach ($results->getConnections() as $person) {
   $names = $person->getNames();
   $fileAs = $person->getFileAses();
   if ($fileAs) {
       $fileAsValue = $fileAs[0]->getValue();
   }
}
```